# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widgetName'

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, subclass

I want to develop a class that inherits from the tkinter menu class. Here is my code so far the implements the class `MyMenu`, creates a test instance `mDummy` afterwards and adds a command.

```
# import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
# define menu class
class MyMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, arg_master=None, **options):
    # call superclass constructors
    super(tk.Menu,self).__init__(arg_master,**options)

#define test command for menu
def testcommand():
    print("This is a test")

#start of the code    
main=tk.Tk()
mDummy=MyMenu(main)
main.config(menu=mDummy)
mDummy.add_command(label="testlabel",command=testcommand)

main.mainloop()
```

the execution of the code results in a type error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widgetName'.
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
(x86)\Python34\MyProjects\tests\test_myUCVMenu.py", line 15, in <module>
    mDummy=MyMenu(main)   
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\MyProjects\tests\test_myUCVMenu.py", line 7, in __init__
    super(tk.Menu,self).__init__(arg_master,**options) 
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widgetName'
```

From the message, I think that the `__init__` operator of the tkinter menu class wants me to give a variable `'widgetName'` as a positional argument, but I couldn't find out the meaning of `"widgetName"` in the docu. May be the error is somewhere else than in the given line but the code crashes at the call of the `__init__` operator?

Comment: You should always use the *current* class in the `super()` call; `MyMenu`, not `tk.Menu`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The best way is to call `super().__init__()` with no arguments though, from Python 3, which seemingly is the case since OP uses `print` as a function.

Comment: Here is the source code of tkinter: http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter-pysrc.html Maybe it helps you. Menu inherits Widget, which inherits BaseWidget, which needs widgetName as init parameter

Comment: By the way, your indentation is wrong: the call to `super` is outside of the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super()` expects your widget name - which is `MyMenu`, not `tk.Menu`

```
 super(MyMenu, self).__init__(arg_master, **options)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, the following works:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, arg_master=None, **options):
        super().__init__(arg_master,**options)

def testcommand():
    print("This is a test")

main=tk.Tk()
mDummy=MyMenu(main)
main.config(menu=mDummy)
mDummy.add_command(label="testlabel",command=testcommand)

main.mainloop()
```

I made two corrections: I re-indented the call to `super` so it is inside of the `__init__` method; and I changed the `super` method itself: Python 3 introduced the `super().__init__()` syntax.

With Python 3.4, I need both changes to get the code to work.